# ROW_NUMBER restart on duplicate value

Tags: duplicates, row-number

I have a result set as shown below and am using the ROW_NUMBER() function to determine when there is a change in value.

```
Date     |  Value  |  RowNumber
2/13/17  |  10     |  1
2/13/17  |  10     |  2
2/13/17  |  10     |  3
2/13/17  |  11     |  1
2/13/17  |  11     |  2
2/13/17  |  10     |  4
2/13/17  |  10     |  5
```

However, here's my problem.

The last 2 rows which have a value of 10 once again, receive a ROW_NUMBER of 4 and 5, continuing from where the previous ROW_NUMBER of 10 left off.

For my purposes, I need the 2nd set of 10s to restart the ROW_NUMBER with 1 and 2 again.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Are there other columns to work with in the result? What's difference between the first set of 10s and the second?

Comment: There are no other columns to help out over here. I am trying to keep track of every time there is a change in Value. It doesn't actually make a difference to me what the Value is, I just need to reset my ROW_NUMBER  whenever there is any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using LAG() to detect a change from the row before and only select the changes.